# How can I find an elementary function producing the first $100$ primes?

Tags: calculus, prime-numbers, approximation, interpolation

The object is to find an elementary function $f(x)$ , which is handy enough to calculate if with a table calculator (not too high degree, not too large (or small) coefficients) with the following property :

For $n=1,\cdots,100$ , the value $f(n)$ , correct rounded to the next integer, should be the $n-th$ prime.

At first sight, this is easy, because we only need an accuracy of about $0.5$, but I did not succeed with Tchebycheff-approximation.

I also tried to divide $n$ by $100$ and $f(n)$ by $541$ to have values between $0$ and $1$. But in this case, I need a much higher accuracy, because $f(x)$ must be muliplied with $541$.

The main problem is to find a suitable function such as $(a+bx)\ln(cx+d)$ before optimizing the parameters.

> Is there any possibility to find out what kind of elementary function could do the job ?

Particular nice would be a method that could be extended to, lets say, the first $1000$ primes.

Comment: Could you use Lagrange interpolation? Forgive me if this is a trivial suggestion - this is not something I know much about. Edit: such a polynomial is out of the reach of calculation by hand.

Comment: This leads to a polynomial with very large coefficients (consider runges phenomenon)

Comment: I understand now- sorry.

Comment: The correct rounding would be : rounding up. But I would be absolutely confident, if $f(x)$ has sometimes to be rounded "incorrectly".

Comment: trying to use excel solver to set the sum of the squares in the differences to zero

Comment: @Peter, I deleted my comment when I realized I had misread "next" as "nearest."  Maybe you'd be happy with $|f(n)-p_n|\lt1$? (E.g., if $f(25)=96.001$, there'd be no mistaking that $p_{25}=97$ rather than $96$, since (large) primes are always odd.

Comment: @BarryCipra This would be totally sufficient. I would not even bother about the case $f(1)$, which should give $2$ , if the function does the job for the other values.

Comment: If we divide the $n$-th prime by $1.155\cdot n\cdot \ln(n)$, where $6\le n\le 100$, then we get a function oscillating between $0.9588$ and $1.0904$. Maybe, someone can follow this approach !?

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/the-prime-polynomial-generating-prime-numbers)

Comment: @Peter For a low-order approximation (like you example with four coefficients), it is easy enough to search for the optimum solution by exhaustive search, using suitable fractions. For example, with $a,b,c,d = \frac{n}{256}$ I get $\lfloor (0 + 1.125 x) \ln (1.1484375 x + 0.63671875) \rfloor$. Unfortunately, because of the high-frequency components of the function, I *think* an accurate approximation via polynomial or Fourier transform would require roughly as many coefficients as there are discrete function values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that what you try is impossible. Note that although $f$ is increasing,  $f'$ should have many ups and downs. This leaves an $f''$ with a lot of zeros, far from equally spaced.

Consider the primes between $89$ and $131$, for example. Substracting each prime from the next yields:

$$8,4,2,4,2,4,14,4$$

Comment: Once you have a "wiggly function," you might try Fourier series to get something good. Not sure how many terms you'd need.