# Estimate a "prime parabola"?

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, quadratics

I have recently had a thought to construct a parabola by zooming in all the way on a pixel grid, then drawing it in rectangles and zooming out afterwards.

For example, we start by drawing $1\times1$ box in the center of the coordinate system. Then lets make the second stack of blocks bigger by $+1$ on both sides and join them next to the previous block, and repeat. Then join the outer points of the stacks to get a parabola. Image:

[image]

We can work out the formula for this parabola. 

 The $x$s of the points are $0+\frac{1}{2}, 1+\frac{1}{2}, 2+\frac{1}{2}, 3+\frac{1}{2}, 4+\frac{1}{2} \dots$

 The $y$s of the points are $-1+\frac{1}{2}, 0+\frac{1}{2}, 2+\frac{1}{2}, 5+\frac{1}{2},9+\frac{1}{2}\dots$

Meaning the $x$ coordinates have a sequence formula $n-\frac{1}{2}$

 And the $y$ coordinates have a sequence formula $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$

> From that we can work out that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{5}{8}$

---

But what if our stacks are the **prime numbers**? 

First stack centered at $(0,0)$ then is $1\times2$ followed by $1\times3, 1\times5,1\times7,1\times11   \dots$

Since we can't have a sequence that will produce primes, can we at least estimate the $f(x)$ for such a "parabola" for all primes?

Or how can we find such a function that'll be correct for at least first $n$ primes?

---

*"parabola" $\to$ I'm thinking that the construction won't yield a parabola, but a curve that looks similarly to a parabola.*

Comment: You can curve a fit a parabola to three points, but no more. It will only coincidentally hit other points. I think your example works only because a parabola's derivative is 2*x, and you're increasing length by 2 for each width increase of 1.

Comment: @barrycarter I was just thinking about that and noted that in the question.

Comment: You can always fit n points using an n-1 degree polynomial, and primes don't really follow a nice pattern, so I suspect that's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, there is no simple precise formula. But there are estimates.

For example:

1. the number of primes below $n$ is $\pi(n)\approx\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$
2. the $n$'th prime is $p_n\approx n \ln(n)$
3. the sum of the first $n$ primes is $\sum_{k=1}^np_n\approx \frac{n^2}{2}\ln(n)$

(For sources and more precise versions of these formulas, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

So you may take something like $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(x)$, which is indeed similar to a parabola.

Comment: I figured it out and was uploading a picture as you posted your answer, still, thanks! +

Comment: sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The stacks really just sum up to the [Prime Sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html).

Meaning we get the following function that estimates (is similar) to the curve that is being constructed by stacking prime numbers:

$f(x)=\frac{\ln{|x|}}{2}x^2$

[image]

Thus, this estimates all the primes to some degree.

---

For exactly $n$ primes, we can use Lagrange interpolation polynomial of degree $n-1$.

This was done in Mathematica [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6754).